# VBA field to enable label visible in same userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have an  Excel userform named UF1. In this form I have a textbox field where a number is input named Num1. I have a label (named Lab1) which reads as "YES" with visibility on False. I simply want to write code that when the number in Num1 is equal to or greater than 25 the label needs to appear. I have tried this without success.

```
If UF1.Num1 >= 25 Then
   UF1.Lab1.Visable = True.
End If
```

Also, is therjn something extra that needs to be done in order for this to run in real time when inputting the number into the Num1 field?

Comment: `Visable`: Is that a typo in the post or do you have that in your code as well because it should be `Visible`. And where did you put the code? And why do you use the name of the form in the code?

Comment: Was a typo sorry. The code is within another code. I thought putting the userform name in the code would be more specific??

Comment: But why do you expect that this code will run wherever you put it?  Have a look here for the usage of [userforms](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-userform/). Moreover, using the [global default instance](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/userforms_advanced_tips.html) is in most cases a bad idea anyway. BTW, you can always edit your post in order to improve it resp. to fix typos etc.

Comment: Where have you actually put this code? If you want the label's visibility to update "as you type" then you may need to look at hooking into one of the TextBox's events, such as the `Change` or `KeyPress` event. If you want the label to update only when the user (say) presses a button, you can put the code behind the button.